# Multiplying 3 bit number with 3 bit number using 4 bit full adder

Tags: circuit-design

ive been trying to do this for hours to multiply 3 bit number with a 3 bit number ,
can some here tell me whats wrong here ?
[image]

Comment: Using an adder doesn't give multiplication.

Comment: Im also using AND gates as you see

Comment: Just some random observations: You seem to be reversing the significance of your input and your output bits. The first (4-bit) adder will never have a full 5-bit output. Also, how would your largest product fit in the number of bits you're now using as an output? What design is behind this?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to ***a*** four bit adder or four bit adder***s***?

Answer (score 2):

7 * 7 = 49, which needs 6 bits

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of arranging it. Since you have full 4-bit adders to work with, this is pretty easy to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f50U7n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each group of three AND gates represents a ***product term***. And it helps to lay it out so that this is clear. (You need to improve your layout skills.) Clearly laid out, it helps reduce the chances of making mistakes when you hook things up in the schematic.

All that the last adder does is add one part of one product term as the carry-in. But it's necessary. (It could be hooked to the A0 input of the last adder, instead.)

Comment: thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @AsafBenShabat If this is all you needed and you aren't looking for further answers, you may select this answer. Mostly, this helps others avoid wasting their time, if you feel you don't need the time of others in (or considering the idea of) providing further answers. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have all of the adders wired backwards. For instance, a0 AND b1 should feed input 0 instead of input 2.

Also, a0 AND b0 should directly feed the output LSB, bypassing the adders.

Answer (score 0):

You have totally reversed the significance numbering. Bit number 0 is the least significant bit. Your carry with this logic goes to the wrong direction. Maybe it's useful to learn to do the binary multiplication manually on the paper at first.